# How to get field "bikinMain" values from left outer join on multi sum in master table mysql query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    SUM(trowmain)  AS total_trow,
    SUM(trimmain)  AS total_trim,

tblprod_podetails.bikinMain AS qtyBikin

FROM tblprod_poproses 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblprod_podetails
ON tblprod_poproses.poProsesID = tblprod_podetails.poDetailsID
WHERE forming = '1'
```

### when select forming = 1, total trow and qtyMake correct.

```
total_trow | total_trim | qtyMake
    20            0          25
```

### problem : when select forming = 2 total_trim OK, but qtyMake is null

```
total_trow | total_trim | qtyMake
    0           15          null
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the criteria in the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the join:

```
SELECT
    pd.bikinMain AS qtyBikin,
    SUM(trowmain) AS total_trow,
    SUM(trimmain) AS total_trim
FROM tblprod_poproses po
LEFT JOIN tblprod_podetails pd
    ON po.poProsesID = pd.poDetailsID AND
       pd.forming = '1'
GROUP BY
    qtyBikin;
```

Also, your query implies that you really want to be using `GROUP BY`, and aggregating by `qtyBikin`, so I have added that as well.

Comment: thank  for quick respon, 
first sorry for my english.

i already try, may be in my question is't clear. 

i want e.g : outputl if  tblprod.poproses.forming = 1,   the result should : total_trow 10, qtyBikin 25.

if  tblprod.poproses.forming = 2,   the result should : total_trim 15, qtyBikin 30.